# How to create serveral div with "shared border"?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out how to beautifully group divs together to create more creative shapes outline. Basically I wanted to make a textbox with shared border. I've maded a ugly sample over [THERE](http://dabblet.com/gist/e74ce0c79907f61041ffa281ce444967)

```css
.white-box{
width: 300px;
}
.white-box-tab{
position: relative;
left: 8px;
width: 45%;
height: 25px;
background: #fff;
box-shadow: 1px -1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), -1px 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
border-radius: 3px 3px 0px 0px;

text-align: center;
}
.white-box-tab:after{
  content:''; 
  width:100%; 
  height:1px; 
  position:absolute;
  background:white; 
  bottom: -0.5px;
  left: 0px;
}

.white-box-body{
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
background: #fff;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), -1px -1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
border-radius: 0px 3px 3px 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="white-box">
<div class="white-box-tab">
The title
</div>
<div></div>
<div class="white-box-body">
</div>
</div>
```

However, the way I acheive it just feels quite ugly and unexpandable. Is there a better way to complete task like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simply do not apply bottom border to element and move it down by other div border width:

```css
.white-box {
  width: 300px;
}

.white-box .box {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background-color: white;
}

.white-box .box.white-box-tab {
  border-bottom: none;
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  margin-left: 5%;
  width: 70%;
  z-index: 10;
}

.white-box-body {
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="white-box">
  <div class="box white-box-tab">
    The title
  </div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="box white-box-body">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That looks more efficient than mines. However do you think there will be a way to make it always work without using any javascript? For example, if I move that tab to the right or to the corner then our code would stop working.

Comment: @AndrewShi If you move only wrapper `.white-box`, then both `.box` will keep it's positions. No need for JS here

Comment: I mean in terms of that: http://dabblet.com/gist/647c518f20b9814e49b69ea75fd17397. Sorry for the misunderstanding.